# suggest way to increase space between columns in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, listings, columns

Can someone help me understand why the columns are appearing so jammed close to each other?   I'd like some space between the code example and the graphical image.  Do I need to put an empty column between and fill it with white space?

BTW the image is a pdf file, bdd-example.pdf, and the stackexchange interface refuses to allow me to upload the file.  Not sure how make the exact problem reproducible without the image file?  Open to suggestions.  In the mean time the PDF can be downloaded from here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ye10wyi8aUBymZJQ4vr6reGyexDhFQYA/view?usp=sharing

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\mode<presentation>{}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Choice of data structure for MDTD}

  CL s-expression type specifier vs ROBDD for

  $(Z_1\wedge Z_2) \vee (Z_1 \wedge \neg Z_2 \wedge Z_3) \vee (\neg Z_1 \wedge \neg Z_3)$

  \begin{columns}

    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\small]
(or (and Z1 Z2)
    (and Z1 (not Z2) Z3)
    (and (not Z1) (not Z3)))
\end{lstlisting}

    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=3cm]{bdd-example}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: beamer output]

Comment: Your listing is much wider then `.3\textwidth`, while your image is smaller then `.3\textwidth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As what @samcarter said, changing `0.3\textwidth` for `0.5\textwidth` (**ONLY change the first one**) would get a good shape. See the following codes.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\mode<presentation>{}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Choice of data structure for MDTD}

  CL s-expression type specifier vs ROBDD for

  $(Z_1\wedge Z_2) \vee (Z_1 \wedge \neg Z_2 \wedge Z_3) \vee (\neg Z_1 \wedge \neg Z_3)$

  \begin{columns}

    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\small]
(or (and Z1 Z2)
    (and Z1 (not Z2) Z3)
    (and (not Z1) (not Z3)))
\end{lstlisting}

    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=3cm]{bdd-example}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The following is the PDF style
[image]

Comment: A figure in such answers is almost a must (+1 for adding a screenshot ...in the future)

Comment: @koleygr I don't have the `bbd-example` figure.

Comment: You could take a screensot from his question (with the width option the real size doesn't realyy matters so much) or you could use example-image-a from graphicx package...

Comment: @Jim Newton By the way, you should draw the figure with `tikz` package since the font of the words in the figure is different from those in the beamer.

Comment: @koleygr As what you'd like to see, I add the "must"!

Comment: Nice... The reason I asked for that is to help you (as an older member) to make better posts... Your post now is better because I don't have to compile to see if your answer is good enough for me (I see it is not : kidding :P )... This way is easier for me as a user to find what I am looking for... to upvote or to suggest another solution etc...

Comment: @Kuttens,   about drawing the picture with tikz, I don't think that's possible.  Drawing it with graphviz, graphviz can decide the placement, and in my article I have many many of such figures.   I certainly do not want to encode the coordinates of all the graph nodes.

However, perhaps you (or someone) might suggest a way to do this in tikz without having to specify the exact coordinates?